# Spring Security authorization for custom usergroups

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-security, authorization

I am trying to implement a web application with spring security. I understand the role based mechanism of spring security and can get it to work. My problem is, in my web app users can create there own groups and add friends (other users of the app) to it. The access to some pages of the user is based on this friends-group. It should work similar to facebook user and groups.
How can I implement these custom user groups and the access to users pages with spring security? Is there a default mechanism for this use case? Or should I implement my own DB tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using user groups with ACL mechanism. Basically I make sure that when ACL is created for an object the owner is set. Then when another user tries to access this object the owner's groups are checked to see if there is a match.

This of course means that when user changes his groups then the object 'goes with him'.

If you don't want this behavior you can have group object's ACL as a parent acl for a secure object. Then when a user changes groups you should set the correct entries for group object ACL. This way the secure object is tied to the user group not the user himself.

[Spring Security Domain Object Security (ACLs)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html)

Comment: Do you know where I can find a code example on the net?

Comment: For the user groups or ACL as a whole? I'm sure you can find a lot of examples about how to setup ACL and the user groups functionality (as I implemented it) is a piece of cake compared to setting up ACL :) I basically just created my own **PermissionEvaluator** and in checkPermission method I just retrieve two users - ACL owner and current user from SecurityContext and then I compare their groups. [AclPermissionEvaluator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/acl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/acls/AclPermissionEvaluator.java) - Spring implementation